# Name of App in App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store

I want to submit an app to the app store.

The app has been developed with one name all along - "Monkeys". However, now it needs to be changed to "Apes".

Do I just need to change the Bundle display name to "Apes"? If I do this, it appears as "Apes" in the simulator and device, but the Product is still called Monkeys.app.  Should I worry that it still has the old name?

If I change 'Executable file' there is a build fail.

Comment: Is this like the QBASIC game gorilla? ;)

Comment: Change the product name in your info.plist!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change the "Product Name" in the target for your app in order to change the name of the app bundle that is built. You can find this setting under the "Build" tab of the target inspector.

Answer (score 14):

### 1. Application name on App Store

This is the name that you write on itunesconnect.apple.com while uploading/adding application on app store for review. This name is displayed on App Store after get published.

### 2. Application name on Device/Simulator

This is the name you can set/change from info.plist file>Bundle Display Name. If the Display name and Application name given on itunesconnect is different or same. it is fine. no issue at all.

### 3. Project Name

This can be renamed using Xcode>Project>Rename. This will rename all the associated Bundle and product name.

Generally we are used to give application name same as project name. but as per your desciption what you can do is.

1. Keep your project name **Monkeys**
2. Write display name in info.plist>Bundle Display name : **Apes**
3. You can keep **Monkeys** or **Apes** in Itunesconnect if not registered yet by someone else

This will work perfectly fine. no issue at all.

Hope this helps

Thanks
Vivek Navadia

Answer (score 0):

What I did was start with [Rename Xcode Project](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/17683).

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in the Info.plist of the app's project folder under the Bundle Name.