# App store name and info.plist

Tags: iphone, sdk, info.plist

I've just completed my first app and having tested I'm ready for submission.

However, despite numerous web searches and reading, I'm struggling to finalise the method required to enable me to have a different name on the app store to the name that appears under the app on the device home screen.

In the `info.plist` file there is reference to bundle display name, executable name, bundle name, bundle identifier, product name etc.

So, for example, say I would like the app store name to display as:

```
HELLO WORLD
```

and I would like the name below the icon on the device home screen to display as:

```
HELLO
```

How should I enter the data in the `info.plist` file to achieve the above?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Gav.

Comment: Check similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081011/name-of-app-in-app-store)
This will resolve your problem

Answer (score 10):

The name on the App. Store is set when you submit the app, on the Apple webpage, not in code.

To change the name on the Springboard modify the Info.plist changing *Bundle Display Name* property from ${PRODUCT_NAME} to the desired name.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys.

So just to confirm, the name of the product / bundle within the info.plist can be slightly different to that which is submitted via the Apple webpage?

Comment: I suppose the policy of Apple avoid "too much different" names.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I just better submit it and see what happens! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode with your project in view, go to the menu Project | Edit Active Target. In the dialog that appears select the Build tab. Make sure the Configuration drop down has "All Configurations" selected and the Show drop down has "All Settings" selected. In the search field enter "Product Name". One setting should be shown at this point - the product name. Change value as needed.