# Delphi ios app gets wrong name on phone when in release build

Tags: ios, delphi

This may seem like a stupid question. But when I make a debug build, my app gets the correct name on the "ios desktop". When I use release build, it gets the name of the app I made some time ago.

- I have been into project settings and changed it for all similar/device debug/release modes.
- I have also made a Windows search and replaced all places found.

I do also use other provision profiles, but I am still wondering if it could be something like that? But I just do not believe that can be the case... So clearly me + Windows search is missing something somewhere....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the the name in your .plist for the *Bundle Display Name*. That is the the name of the end product. check this similar question [App store name and info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874553/app-store-name-and-info-plist)

Comment: Thanks - you were correct! I will save this for future reference as well :)